# Proof using Cauchy's mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that if the function $f$ is differentiable on the closed interval $[1,2]$, then there exists a point $\xi \in (1,2)$, such that $f(2)-f(1)= \frac{\xi^2}{2} f'(\xi)$

I would like to know if this is correct:

Let $t=\frac{1}{x}$, $g(t) = \frac{1}{t}$. 
Then we have curve given parametically that is equivalent to our original function $f(x)$:

(this is the part I'm not sure of:)

$f(t)=f(\frac{1}{x})$

$g(t)=\frac{1}{t}$

By Cauchy's theorem, there exists a point $\xi \in (1,2)$, such that:
$$\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{g(2)-g(1)}=\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{\frac{1}{2}-1}=\frac{f'(\xi)}{-\xi^{-2}}$$
$$f(2)-f(1)=\frac{\xi^2}{2}f'(\xi)$$

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: fixed interval $(1,2)$

Comment: Well, the ideas of the proof are there, but not written properly. You are applying Cauchy's mean value theorem to the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)=1/x$, which are differentiable on $(1,2)$ and continuous on $[1,2]$. Moreover, $g'$ doesn't vanish on $(1,2)$, and $g(2)\neq g(1)$. Then the theorem gives you the existence of $\zeta$ such that $-2(f(2)-f(1))=\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{g(2)-g(1)}=\frac{f'(\zeta)}{g'(\zeta)}=-\zeta^2f'(\zeta)$.